# Fuga de memoria en cliente MySQL en C

Tags: mysql, c

Este programa me está fugando 2 bloques de memoria y no logro liberarla. Además, solamente tengo la intención de abrir la conexión a MySQL.

Éste es mi código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mysql.h"
int main(int argc, char argv[]) {
    MYSQL *conn = mysql_init(NULL);
    /* ^ total heap usage: 58 allocs, 56 frees, 89,835 bytes allocated*/
    /*if(!conn) {puts("Connection don't successfull.");}
    if(!mysql_real_connect(conn,"127.0.0.1","exTerminator","01abC","db_alaxa",3306,((void*)NULL),0)) {fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",mysql_error(conn));}
    mysql_close(conn);*/

    puts("Press ENTER to exit");
    getc(stdin);
    return (0);}
```

Como pueden apreciar solo está la intención de inicializar la conexión.

Comment: Pues seguramente sea porque abres la conexión y no la cierras, ¿ no ?

Comment: Nada ya lo revise cambiando 
mysql_close(conn);*/
por
*/mysql_close(conn);
Y nada.

Comment: ¿Qué herramienta estás usando para medir los bloques de memoria que quedan alojados en memoria tras la finalización del programa? ¿`valgrind`? Si solo has medido el uso de `mysql_init()`, entonces es normal que haya bloques de memoria que no han sido liberados, puesto que son necesarios para gestionar la conexión (aunque aún no la hayas abierto hacia el servidor).

Comment: He encontrado el problema. Redactando respuesta.

Comment: Si, estoy utilizando valgrind; pero aunque habilite mysql_close(conn) siguen esos bloques sin ser liberados.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El principal problema que estás sufriendo es debido a que no sigues [las instrucciones del manual de la interfaz básica del API C](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/c-api-8.0-en/c-api-basic-interface-usage.html):

> 1. Initialize the MySQL client library by calling `mysql_library_init()`.
> 2. Initialize a connection handler by calling `mysql_init()` and connect to the server by calling a connection-establishment function such as `mysql_real_connect()`.
> 3. Issue SQL statements and process their results.
> 4. Close the connection to the MySQL server by calling `mysql_close()`.
> 5. End use of the MySQL client library by calling `mysql_library_end()`.

En castellano:

> 1. Inicializa la biblioteca del cliente de MySQL llamando a `mysql_library_init()`.
> 2. Inicializa un manipulador de conexión llamando a `mysql_init()` y estableciendo una conexión con el servidor llamando a una función de establecimiento como `mysql_real_connect()`.
> 3. Haga consultas SQL y procese sus resultados.
> 4. Cierre la conexión al servidor MySQL llamando a `mysql_close()`.
> 5. Finalice el uso de la biblioteca del cliente de MySQL llamando a `mysql_library_end()`.

Es decir, que tu código debería ser:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mysql.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    MYSQL conn;
    /* Inicializamos la biblioteca de cliente de MySQL */
    mysql_library_init(0, NULL, NULL);
    /* Pasamos como referencia la estructura existente */
    mysql_init(&conn);
    /*if(!conn) {puts("Connection don't successfull.");}
    if(!mysql_real_connect(conn,"127.0.0.1","exTerminator","01abC","db_alaxa",3306,((void*)NULL),0)) {fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",mysql_error(conn));}
    mysql_close(conn);*/

    /* Cerramos la conexión */
    mysql_close(&conn);
    /* Finalizamos el uso de la biblioteca de cliente de MySQL */
    mysql_library_end();
    puts("Press ENTER to exit");
    getc(stdin);
    return (0);
}
```

De modo que `valgrind` dejaría de quejarse de cualquier bloque de memoria no liberado:

```
$ gcc -o prueba -Wall --pedantic prueba.c $(mysql_config --cflags --libs)
$ valgrind --leak-check=full ./prueba
==20200== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==20200== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==20200== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==20200== Command: ./prueba
==20200== 
Press ENTER to exit

==20200== 
==20200== HEAP SUMMARY:
==20200==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20200==   total heap usage: 4,574 allocs, 4,574 frees, 242,640 bytes allocated
==20200== 
==20200== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==20200== 
==20200== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==20200== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

---

Si no lo haces de esta manera, el resultado que te daría `valgrind` sería el siguiente (usando `mysql_close()`, en caso contrario habría muchas más líneas de fugas de memoria):

```
==19821== 
==19821== HEAP SUMMARY:
==19821==     in use at exit: 88 bytes in 2 blocks
==19821==   total heap usage: 4,574 allocs, 4,572 frees, 242,640 bytes allocated
==19821== 
==19821== 56 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 2 of 2
==19821==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==19821==    by 0x48FBA07: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.21.2.27)
==19821==    by 0x48FA270: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.21.2.27)
==19821==    by 0x4895004: mysql_server_init (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.21.2.27)
==19821==    by 0x489FF38: mysql_init (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.21.2.27)
==19821==    by 0x109202: main (in /tmp/pruebas)
==19821== 
==19821== LEAK SUMMARY:
==19821==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19821==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19821==      possibly lost: 56 bytes in 1 blocks
==19821==    still reachable: 32 bytes in 1 blocks
==19821==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19821== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==19821== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==19821== 
==19821== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==19821== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: Efectivamente, esas dos funciones realizan su trabajo.Graicas por la colaboracion y el material de apoyo.

Comment: Un placer ser de ayuda. Recuerda marcar la respuesta como correcta pulsando en el icono **✓** que hay a la izquierda. Gracias.